# Advices to correctly manage threads

Tags: lotus-domino, javaagents

I have a big Domino Web application, which uses numerous calls "OpenAgent" to Java agents to retrieve data via ajax. The application is used by several users.

What are the main parameters that you advise me to check and adjust on server, in order to avoid HTTP hang or performance issues?

Answer (score 2):

There is quite an overhead in calling to an agent be it LotusScript or Java. So if your AJAX calls are quite frequent you are going to overload the server easily.

Domino comes with a test tool for this called [Server.Load](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_INTRODUCING_SERVER_LOAD_OVER.html). It will allow you to emulate a heavy load server and you will see how your code performs under that. Another I've used is Rational Functional Tester ([trial version](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/functional/)), but there are probably free ones out there as well (eg. JMeter/LoadRunner. I haven't used).

So if you are doing infrequent complex actions that may take time and don't need a quick response to the user, I would recommend to continue with the web agent.

If it is simple look up calls I would recommend to use alternative methods. For example XPages has the AJAX functionality built into it with scaling in mind. Or if it is JSON data then look into [Domino Data Service](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Domino%20Data%20Service#action=openDocument&content=catcontent&ct=prodDoc), or [Domino URL commands](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Domino_URL_cheat_sheet/).